# How to forbid shortcuts deletion from the desktop

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, desktop, shortcuts

I'm looking how to forbid a limited XP user from deleting a shortcut from the desktop.

I've been trying to set the *Security permissions* but I can't apply them to a shortcut.

can someone help me on this ? without any 3rd-party tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the shortcuts to the "C:\Documents and settings\all users\desktop" folder, and if the user is a limited user, then they should not be able to delete the shortcuts.